# How to change parameters Runtime in Omnet++ with setDoubleValue()

Tags: omnet++

I am simulating a network with 2 wireless hosts and 1 Access point. During runtime a node sets the Access Point's transmit power to zero (to turn it off) by accessing the module and using setDoubleValue(0). But the new values never takes effect. AP's msgs continue to reach the nodes. What am I doing wrong here? I want to turn access point off while the simulation is running. Please help.

```
cSimulation *currentSimulation = getSimulation();
cModule *tx = nullptr;
tx=currentSimulation->getModuleByPath("agranet.ap.wlan[0].radio.transmitter");
tx->par("power").setDoubleValue(0);

//cPar& po = tx->par("power");
//po.setDoubleValue(0);
```

I want to turn the access point off while simulation is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the power parameter after initialization because it is a non-volatile parameter, so its value is read at initialization and cached afterwards. You can manipulate only volatile NED parameters where the C++ code is already prepared for this.

On the other hand, what you are trying to achieve is to disable a node at a certain time, which is what ScenaioManager is for:

https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/users-guide/ch-scenario-scripting.html